# NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency if target folder is not present

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Currently my NetBeans 8.0 has been doing the strangest thing.

I have a multimodule project. Usually I did not even have to have the projects opened or even downloaded, if the modules were in maven repository. Currently, some of my modules however need to be opened and built, so that "target" folder is in the project directory filled with classes. If it is not, I get a NoClassDefFoundError.

The error looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SOME/CLASS/THAT/IS/EXPECTED/IN/TARGET/FOLDER/OF/SOME/MODULE/THAT/IS/A/DEPENDENCY
at ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.SOME.CLASS.THAT.IS.EXPECTED.IN.TARGET.FOLDER.OF.SOME.MODULE.THAT.IS.A.DEPENDENCY
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 2 more
```

My POM looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>some</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://someconnection</developerConnection>
</scm>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>sometagbase/tags</tagBase>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myModuleGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>somModule1</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
      ...... many of these here
</dependencies>
```

Why does it suddenly require a target folder with classes? Is it not supposed to get them from the dependencies? From the repository?

Comment: The dependencies aren't usually stored in the target directory. They are usually somwhere out of the project directory as a whole. If the repository is in the target directory by any luck, there would be some problems but I think they would be different.

Comment: The dependencies as jars are stored in local repository which is in the .m2 directory or are deployed to our company remote repository, from which maven fetches them. However, this time it seemed like if I had not built the dependencies locally, thus creating the target folder in the dependencies´ folders, this error occurred. However, this should not be necessary. It means that if I want to use module, that is using 8 more modules, I would have to download all the modules and build them locally - which beats the purpose of having a maven repository altogether

Answer (score 0):

Open maven tab at right side of the editor and run double click all options of life cycle and try to see if folder finally generated

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).